# How do I maintain state between CloudFormation stacks and local CDK development when iterating on a project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I'm starting a small project with AWS CDK. I have created a bucket with CDK.

```
this.myBucket = new s3.Bucket(this,'my-first-bucket',{
  removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
});
```

When I deploy this using `cdk deploy`, CloudFormation creates a bucket using a generated bucket name, like `mystack-myfirstbucket786ee605-1q912cjgtpj27`.

Now, I start writing a lambda function, whose job will entail writing to this bucket. I pass the bucketName to the lambda by adding it to the lambda's environment variable.

```
this.myLambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "my-function",{
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'myFunction.handler',
  runtime:  lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
  memorySize: 256,
  timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60)
});

this.myLambdaFunction.addEnvironment('bucket', this.myBucket.bucketName );
```

When I run the lambda locally, as I iterate on developing it, if I inspect the `process.env.bucket` in my lambda, I see that it has a different generated bucket name i.e.`myfirstbucket786ee605` that is different that the bucket that CloudFormation created. This prevents my lambda from writing to that bucket while I develop locally.

How am I supposed to maintain the CloudFormation state in between my local and AWS environment as I develop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your lambda you can do this

```
this.myLambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "my-function",{
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'myFunction.handler',
  runtime:  lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
  memorySize: 256,
  environment: {
    s3BucketName: this.myBucket.bucketName
  }
  timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60)
});
```

Then in your code that runs in the lambda you can get the bucket name as:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
   let s3BucketName = process.env.s3BucketName;
}
```

That should get you the environment name you need.

**Side note**: If you go to AWS lambda page and navigate to your lambda you can go to configuration and see what environment variables were saved.

**Update 2**
Another way you can do it is modify your stack that creates the bucket store the bucket name in SSM StringParameter such as:

```
new ssm.StringParameter(this, 'My Bucket Name', {
  parameterName: 'My Bucket Name',
  stringValue:  this.myBucket.bucketName
});
```

Then in the stack that you create your lambda in you can get your bucket name and set the variable that way

```
let s3BucketName = ssm.StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(this, 'My Bucket Name');

this.myLambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, "my-function",{
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'myFunction.handler',
  runtime:  lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
  memorySize: 256,
  environment: {
    s3BucketName: s3BucketName
  }
  timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60)
});
```

Another thing you can try is to fetch the ssm value in the lambda using `aws-sdk`:
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
export const handler = async (event) => {

```
 let ssm = new AWS.SSM({
   region: <region>,
   accessKeyId: '',
   secretAccessKey: ''
 });

  var params = {
    Name: 'My Bucket Name',
    WithDecryption: true || false
  }
    
  let s3Bucket = '';
  await ssm.getParameter(params).promise().then((data) => {
    s3Bucket = data.Parameter.Value
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe your change the same function with a different method than mine for assigning the environment variable to the lambda. This works fine if the lambda and bucket are both running in the same aws enviroment

The issue I'm running into is that once my stack is deployed, my local setup does not have context to the resources that have already been created, as my stack is account agnostic.

Is there a way to reference the stack already created in my account?

Comment: See my edit. you can save your bucket name in a string parameter in SSM then retrieve that parameter in either your lambda stack or your lambda handler.